# Indexing in SOLR: correcting the analyzer to not produce immense terms

Tags: indexing, solr, nutch, analyzer, fieldtype

I'm trying to index my nutch crawled data by running:

```
bin/nutch index -D solr.server.url="http://localhost:8983/solr/carerate" crawl/crawldb -linkdb crawl/linkdb crawl/segments/2016*
```

At first it was working totally Ok. I indexed my data, sent a few queries and recieved good results. But then I ran the crawling again, so that it fetches more pages, and now when I run the nutch index command, I face with

> java.io.IOException: Job failed!

here is my hadoop log:

> java.lang.Exception: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer$RemoteSolrException: Exception writing document id http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~frank/About_Me/about_me.html to the index; possible analysis error: Document contains at least one immense term in field="content" (whose UTF8 encoding is longer than the max length 32766), all of which were skipped.  Please correct the analyzer to not produce such terms.  The prefix of the first immense term is: '[70, 114, 97, 110, 107, 32, 82, 117, 100, 122, 105, 99, 122, 32, 45, 32, 65, 98, 111, 117, 116, 32, 77, 101, 32, 97, 98, 111, 117, 116]...', original message: bytes can be at most 32766 in length; got 40063. Perhaps the document has an indexed string field (solr.StrField) which is too large
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:462)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:529)
>   Caused by: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer$RemoteSolrException: Exception writing document id http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~frank/About_Me/about_me.html to the index; possible analysis error: Document contains at least one immense term in field="content" (whose UTF8 encoding is longer than the max length 32766), all of which were skipped.  Please correct the analyzer to not produce such terms.  The prefix of the first immense term is: '[70, 114, 97, 110, 107, 32, 82, 117, 100, 122, 105, 99, 122, 32, 45, 32, 65, 98, 111, 117, 116, 32, 77, 101, 32, 97, 98, 111, 117, 116]...', original message: bytes can be at most 32766 in length; got 40063. Perhaps the document has an indexed string field (solr.StrField) which is too large
>       at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.executeMethod(HttpSolrServer.java:552)
>       at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.request(HttpSolrServer.java:210)
>       at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.request(HttpSolrServer.java:206)
>       at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.AbstractUpdateRequest.process(AbstractUpdateRequest.java:124)
>       at org.apache.nutch.indexwriter.solr.SolrIndexWriter.close(SolrIndexWriter.java:153)
>       at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexWriters.close(IndexWriters.java:115)
>       at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexerOutputFormat$1.close(IndexerOutputFormat.java:44)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask$OldTrackingRecordWriter.close(ReduceTask.java:502)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:456)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:392)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$ReduceTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:319)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   2016-06-21 13:27:37,994 ERROR indexer.IndexingJob - Indexer: java.io.IOException: Job failed!
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:836)
>       at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.index(IndexingJob.java:145)
>       at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.run(IndexingJob.java:222)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
>       at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.main(IndexingJob.java:231)

What I realize is that in the mentioned page there must be a really long term. 
So in schema.xml(in nutch) and managed-schema(in solr) I changed the type of "id", "content",and "text" from "strings" to "text_general" :
But it didn't solve the problem.

I'm no expert, so I'm not sure how to correct the analyzer without screwing up something else. I've read that I can:
1. use (in index analyzer), a LengthFilterFactory in order to filter out those tokens that don't fall withing a requested length range.
2.use (in index analyzer), a TruncateTokenFilterFactory for fixing the max length of indexed tokens

but there are so many analyzer in the schema. should I change the analyzer defined for  ? if yes since the content and other fields' type are text_general, isn't it gonna affect all of them too?

Anyone knows how can I fix this problem? I would really appreciate any help.

BTW, I am using nutch 1.11 and solr 6.0.0.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you're using the `schema.xml` bundled with Nutch as the base schema for your Solr installation, basically you'll just need to add either of those filters (`LengthFilterFactory` or `TruncateTokenFilterFactory`) to the `text_general` field type.

Starting from the initial definition of the `text_general` `fieldType` (https://github.com/apache/nutch/blob/master/conf/schema.xml#L108-L123) you'll need to add the following to the `<analyzer type="index">` section:

```
...
<analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <!-- remove long tokens -->
    <filter class="solr.LengthFilterFactory" min="3" max="7"/> 
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
...
```

This could also be applied to the `query` analyzer using the same syntax. If you want to use the `TruncateTokenFilterFactory` filter just swap the added line with:

```
 <filter class="solr.TruncateTokenFilterFactory" prefixLength="5"/>
```

Also, don't forget to adjust the parameters of each filter to your needs (`min`, `max` for the `LengthFilterFactory`) and `prefixLength` for the `TruncateTokenFilterFactory`.

Answering your other questions: yes this would affect all fields with the `text_general` type but this is not so problematic because if you find another super-long term in any other field, the same error will be thrown. If you still want to isolate this change just for the `content` field, just create a new `fieldType` with a new name (`truncated_text_general`, for instance, just copy&paste the entire `fieldType` section and change the name attribute) and then change the type of the `content` field (https://github.com/apache/nutch/blob/master/conf/schema.xml#L339) to match your newly created `fieldType`.

That being said, just select sane values for the filters to avoid missing a lot of terms from your index.

Comment: Thanks for your response Jorge. Though you explained really good that how it works, as I mentioned in my Question body, I did tried this, and unfortunately it did not solved the problem for me.